# Is it possible to add two selectors for one component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am wondering and cannot find anywhere if it is possible or not to add multiple selectors for one component in angular. For example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-1', 'my-app-2'
})
```

Of course, that example does not work. Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem, why do you want a component to have multiple selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, just a comma separated string. Example from Angular Material source code:

```js
selector: 'table[editable], cdk-table[editable], mat-table[editable]',
```

Answer (score 1):

yes kind of - the best way is to extend one component to another then your will have two selectors, in a directive you can list multiple selectors to attach them to the Dom.  There are few specific instances where this is a good idea, but I've found that each person has their own particular needs.

**your.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'selector-1',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  title = 'hi mom';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'selector-2',
    templateUrl: './your.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class OtherComponent extends YourComponent {
}
```

**someotheradjacent.component.html**

```
<app-selector-1></app-selector-1>
<app-selector-2></app-selector-2>
```